# Sorting an array in reverse order - not reversing

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, reverse

I am trying to sort an array of integers from highest to lowest.

```
int[] array = {2, 6, 4, 1};    
Arrays.sort(array);
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(array));
for (int num : array) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

This prints the array in an ascending order - `1, 2, 4, 6`. Why is it not being reversed, or why is the array not being permanently stored in its reversed state?

Comment: I understand. Can I store this list, and then convert it back into an array? Or is there any easier way to reverse sort an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most "easy" solution would be to use the `reverseComperator` provided by the `Collections` class. This will automaticly sort the array in a descending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Use the Wrapper class, otherwise you can´t call Arrays.sort with a comperator.
    Integer[] array = {2, 6, 4, 1};
    Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int num : array) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

As why your solution doesn´t work.
You temporarly create a List with `Arrays.asList(array)`, which you do reverse and that isn´t refered to anymore afterwards. This wont change the order for the `array` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying the result of sorting the array, not the result of reversing the list. You would need to store the sorted list in a temporary variable, reverse it, then call toArray to get the desired behavior.

The more straightforward way to sort in reverse order is to do:

```
Arrays.sort(array, (o1,o2)-> Integer.compare(o2,o1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code: `Arrays.asList` does not create a new `List<Integer>`, it's actually a `List<int[]>`. But even if it worked as you expected, the returned list is only a temporary object, you're still printing the array.

Unfortunately, the correct solution is not very elegant:

```
int[] array = {2, 6, 4, 1};    
Arrays.sort(array);
List<Integer> asList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
for(int i : array) {
    asList.add(i);
}
Collections.reverse(asList);
for (int num : asList) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```